# What does this screen shot mean?

Tags: mining

I signed up for ethereum on my mac. I followed the instructions and this has been what has been going on since right after midnight last night. There is process, I'm just not sure what is going on. Am I mining?

[image: This is a screen shot of what I believe is the mining process.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That screenshot means,

1. You are using a MacOS. :D
2. Starting up [Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) of [Ethereum blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum).
3. Mist is started downloading the blockchain data to your computer
4. There are 4 [peers connected](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/connecting-to-the-network.html) to your computer.
5. You are at block `2124107` of `3790605`
6. ### Mist is asking you to choose the network which you want to use

   - You can either choose main net to mine real ETH or testnet

[image]

Comment: What benefit(s) are there to downloading the blockchain to your computer?

Comment: You need entire Blockchain to validate previous transactions; say you want to send from your wallet then you need this or some other means. This is the way how Mist works.

Comment: What is the relevance of the picture here? Does the "test network" in the Mist screenshot correspond to one of the code names?

Answer (score 2):

It means you can either use the test network or main network to develop contracts.

Comment: Not only for developing contracts. +1